# Autodesk Inventor 2013 Support

Tags: printing, help-files, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to print the entire Autodesk Inventor and/or Inventor Pro help documentation.

Due to the formatting of the `.htm` files, when I print them, they come out lacking crutial content. (Usually only headers print... even if I change the page style)

Is there some `.pdf` or some other complete (compiled) guide that I can print (even if it is hundreds or thousands of pages long).

Additionally, Adobe Acrobat Pro can't convert the `.htm` files into a `PDF`.

Comment: As far as i'm aware, what you would like to do is not directly possible. You could convert the HTM files you require to PDF, and then print them (making sure to scale them to the page).

Comment: @OliverG I haven't been able to do this.  Do you know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see what you mean.  After downloading both the standard Help file installer and the LT versions, you can't print them, because you can't get at the file shown in the frame... it only wants to print the main contents frame.  And, if you open any of the individual .htm files in the directory, it forces the table of contents.

Also, 2011 was the last year that Autodesk offered the help file in a PDF format.  From what I'm reading [here](http://www.blog.cadnauseam.com/2012/04/06/autocad-2013-an-autodesk-help-writer-responds/) which is a conversation with one of the guys who actually worked on the 2013 help system, they dropped the PDF format in exchange for something that was easier to navigate and search through, considering the sheer size of the help system.  Their goal was not to produce something that was easy to print, but to produce something that was easy to get to the information you need... whether you were online or offline... and to avoid using the Microsoft CHM help file format in the process.

No one else has take the time to take apart the all the information, and put it back together into a PDF file.  This could be an opportunity for you to do just that.  I imagine that all those who would be interested in printing out the help documentation would appreciate it.  On the other hand, if you look at this as just an enormous amount of work with very little pay off... you can probably imagine why no one else has done it either.

Comment: I was really hoping there was an answer... I'll upvote for the effort, but I'll wait to accept you answer as *the* answer until I know that there really is no other way...

Comment: @wizlog there is a ton of discussion on this very same topic on the Autodesk support forums, as well as a few other forums.  There are others who were interested in a PDF version, but there were some very specific responses as to why the current Help version is in the form it is in.  Like I implied.  You would have to edit every HTML file to not force the frame, and then open each to print each.  There is no automatic way to open each document in the proper order to print it all to a single PDF file.

Comment: I had found the PDF that soandos just posted...  but something doesn't seem right... I found a link to that PDF from an Autodesk site...  Is it actually the support documentation?

Comment: @Wizlog it does appear to be a manual for using Inventor Fusion, albeit a poorly made one.  For example, no title page, all the images extend off the page to the right, incomplete index at the end, etc.  The Copyright at the end is from 2012, for 2013 software.  I'd say someone other than

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to jump in here and say that Bon Gart is absolutely correct. The official "manuals" for the 2013 Autodesk products are not available in PDF format. We have chosen to go with an online help method which allows for editing, updating and adding new features when necessary. This method also makes it easier to search and find the topics you are looking for.

You can find the Inventor 2013 online Wikihelp right here: http://wikihelp.autodesk.com/Inventor/enu/2013

Your feedback on this is very appreciated!

If you have any more questions or need any further help from Autodesk you can find us on  our brand new support blog:

http://autodeskcare.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the conformation that Bon Gart is correct is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://de0qmbqba3hfm.cloudfront.net/attachments/67242/0) is the documentation in full.

Hope it is what you are looking for.